# Double encode for JSON

Tags: php, javascript, ampersand, double-quotes, encodeuricomponent

In most of my AJAX functions I have to double encode free text entered by a user, i.e. I have to do encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent(myString)).

If I do it just once most symbols except double quotes and long hyphens work.

If I alert out the result from a single encode quotes are encoded, but it breaks the JSON string which is why I am confused.

Is this a bug with JavaScript or am I missing something? Is it related to the way that you have to double encode ampersand in PHP to get it to work?

---

Hi,

Here is the code that lets a user store a note against something:

```
function saveAdminNote() {

var note = encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent($('#adminNote').val().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,""))) ;
JSON = '{"mode":"UPDATE_INTNOTE", "jobid":'+jobId+', "note":"'+note+'"}' ;

clearTimeout(tOut2) ;
tOut2 = setTimeout(function(){             
    $.ajax({
        data: 'dataString='+JSON,
        url: 'core/job-builder-controlV2.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            if(data)
            {
                $.prompt(data) ;
            }
        }
    })

}, 250) ;

}
```

---

So if my data structure is flat, there is no advantage to using JSON at all?

I was under the impression that JSON gave a little more security?

Comment: You are missing something, but it is hard to tell what as we can't see the code that constructs your requests or generates your output.

Comment: You should not have to double encode. Please show us your code.

Comment: No, you do not need to double encode values. It's something you are doing wrong in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that you are trying to construct JSON by mashing together strings (instead of using a JSON library) … and encoding parts of those strings (instead of encoding the resulting JSON string (i.e. the non-URI data that you want to put into the URI) … which jQuery will do for you).

If you want to submit JSON as part of a form encoded data request, then you would:

```
$.ajax({
    data: { 
        dataString: JSON.stringify({ 
            "mode": "UPDATE_INTNOTE", 
            "jobid": jobId, 
            "note": $('#adminNote').val() 
        })
    }, 
    …
```

Since you have a flat data structure here (i.e. no objects or arrays in the data) then you don't need to use JSON at all.

```
$.ajax({
        data: { 
            "mode": "UPDATE_INTNOTE", 
            "jobid": jobId, 
            "note": $('#adminNote').val() 
            },
```

(Then, in your PHP, just access `$_POST['mode']` etc, instead of parsing the JSON and then getting the data from the resulting object)

Comment: Does last advice depends on JSON and PHP objects having similar enough syntax, so you could skip proper decode? In that case I'd really recommend against it.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov — No. It depends (as I said in the answer) on the data structure being flat. If you don't need a complex data structure, then you don't need JSON. If you don't need JSON you don't need to JSON encode, then form encode, then form decode, then JSON decode. You just need to form encode (which passing an object to `data` does) and form decode (which reading data from `$_POST` does).

Answer (score 2):

Do not construct JSON manually, let the correct [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) method do the work for you (and don't overwrite global JSON object too).

```
json = JSON.stringify({
   "mode":"UPDATE_INTNOTE",
   "jobid": jobId,
   "note": $('#adminNote').val() 
})
```